# create a shell script to clone and install

Tags: bash, shell

The following is what I am trying to acheive:

```
git clone git_project_url
cd git_project_url
./install.sh /usr/local
```

This library is requirement for a project and I want to install this library into the already existing install script..

So basically, I am guessing.. the idea is to clone the project into tmp..
and then install it into that specific location... and well halt if the install fails for any particular reason..

How do I automate this in a shell script.
Thanks

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? The above looks fairly reasonable.

Comment: (1) Avoid `cd` in scripts.  (2) Preferably use absolute paths.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Oh.. just adding the above in the shell script would do it.. How do i halt. if there is an error in install?

Comment: Check if `$?` is not 0.

Comment: The entire script should halt if the `./install.sh` part encounters an error. The only reason that wouldn't be the case is if it handles the error(s) internally.

Answer (score 0):

Write your shell script like this:

```
git clone git_project_url &&
    cd git_project_url &&
    ./install.sh /usr/local
```

If either of the first two commands (`git` or `cd`) fails the remaining commands won't be executed.

This won't change the behaviour of `./install.sh` however. If it continues running after encountering errors when you run it from the shell prompt, it will also continue to run after errors when you in this script.